# Qt "find" or "locate" command does not work as expected in QProcess

Tags: c++, bash, qt

I want to write a simple app that searches entire system for files and folders.
However, the application does not work as expected and only finds certain files only which are located in /opt/ and /home. I want to be able to search for any file, regardless of how big of a buffer would require to display it.
I am updating a textEdit content afterwards calling this function:

```
void FileSearch::fileSearch (QString needle)
{
    QProcess file_search_process;
    QString exec = "/usr/bin/find";
    QStringList params;
     params << "/" << "-name" << "*"+needle+"*";
    file_search_process.start(exec,params);
    file_search_process.waitForFinished();
    QByteArray newData=file_search_process.readAll();
    this->result = QString::fromLocal8Bit(newData);
    //std::cout << this->result.toUtf8().constData() << std::endl;
}
```

Also, sometimes nothing is displayed although in a seperate terminal I confirmed that some matches exist. I also tried `"locate" << QStringList() << needle`. Additionaly, I discovered that it is not due to root permissions (I'm still running my application as root), don't know what else to try.

I suspect it might be because of how Qt application handles the process. Any help is greately appreciated.

**EDIT**: The following works fine for me, although it does not actually solve the problem for other people who require to use find or locate:

```
void FileSearch::fileSearch (QString needle)
{
    QDirIterator dirIt("/",QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while (dirIt.hasNext()) {
        dirIt.next();
        if (QFileInfo(dirIt.filePath()).isFile())
            if(dirIt.filePath().contains(needle, Qt::CaseSensitive))
                qDebug()<<dirIt.filePath();
    }
}
```

Comment: "I want to write a simple app that searched entire system for files and folders" - Why? Such programs already exist (in highly optimized form); see `find` and `locate`. Why do you feel you need to wrap them?

Comment: I am pretty sure he is aware of that

Comment: Why? :) Well, that doesn't answer my question. I'll be customizing it for a specific application.

Comment: Having your "find" command use the actual `find` command seems a little weird. If you really want to learn about recursing directories and globbing etc., then why not write it yourself?

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem actually. But still a mystery how this does not work

Comment: If you write the `find` command as is directly into a terminal, do you use quotes around the string you search for? Like `"*foo*"` when looking for files whose names contain `foo`? Not knowing exactly what `QProcess::start` does, you might want to try that (using quotes around the search-string)?

Answer (score 0):

[QProcess::waitForFinished](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForFinished) times out after 30 secs with default `msecs` value. Obviously your QProcess instance gets destroyed while process `/usr/bin/find` is still running and you get only a partial result or no result at all. **If msecs is -1**, the function will not time out.

I prefer using `QProcess::start` method which takes a single string of text containing both the program name and its arguments. With that it's easier to see what you are passing to QProcess.

```
QProcess file_search_process;
QString exec = "/usr/bin/find";
QString command = exec+" /"+" -name"+QString(" *")+needle+QString("*");
qDebug() << command;
file_search_process.start(command);
file_search_process.waitForFinished(-1);
QByteArray newData=file_search_process.readAll();
QString result = QString::fromLocal8Bit(newData);
```

Comment: I could be wrong (CBA to verify), but I don't think QProcess uses a shell to launch the process. The quotes in parameter will then get passed to find, which is probably undesirable.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. Edited the answer. You are right, QProcess doesn't use a shell unless explicitly called. E.g. by changing the above code snippet like this: QString exec = "sh -c find";

Comment: I think in this case you should really use `QStringList` to hold the parameters. That way whitespace in `needle` will not break the command.